# backspace \n \t does not work in long string python argparse

Tags: python, string, argparse

I have the following code, where I am adding a description of a tool

```
usage = r"""
\n-------------------------------------------
Serial Chain Processing\n \
 \n--------------------------------------------

\nSteps. 

1. Buffers to 500 m a shapefile containing the country boundaries in EPSG: 3035 
projection.\n 
2. Clip a continental mask (DLT, GRA, or TCD), to the country boundaries (EPSG:3035)\n
3. Reproject the raster from step 2 to the National Grid using a WKT file 
with the translation parameters.\n 
4. Use the raster calculator to correct the outside areas using the 
following calculation: 

\n\tif(a==1){
    \n\t\toutput=b;
\n\t}
\n\tif(a==0){
    \n\t\toutput = a;
\n\t}
\n\tif(a==1&&IsNoData(b)){
    \n\t\toutput=0;
\n\t}
\n\tif(a==1&&b==255){
    \n\t\toutput=0;
\n}
\n\tif(a==0){
    \n\t\toutput=255;
\n\t}

\nBeing
\n\ta == Binary country boundaries raster in National projection
\n\tb == Raster from Step 3.

\n5. Check for compression, no data, pyramids and create raster attribute table,
as well as the color maps. 
"""

import glob
import subprocess
import os
import gdal 
import osr
import ogr 
import argparse
from osgeo import gdal,osr

def dir_path(string):
    if os.path.isdir(string):
        return string 
    else:
        raise NotADirectoryError(string)

def main(mask, country_bound_LAEA, country_bound_NAT):

    """Initializes the workflow."""
    pass 


if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=usage)
    parser.add_argument('--mask',metavar="", type=dir_path, help = "National Product in LAEA")
    parser.add_argument('--country_bound_LAEA',metavar="", type=dir_path, help = "Country national boundaries in LAEA - Shapefile")
    parser.add_argument('--WKT_file',metavar="", type=dir_path, help = "WKT File derived from the national boundaries raster")
    parser.add_argument('--country_bound_NAT',metavar="", type=dir_path, help = "National Boundaries, binary raster dataset")
    parser.parse_args()
    #main(mask, country_bound_LAEA, country_bound_NAT)
```

When I run python  -h, it print the description stored in `usage`, but the `\n` and `\t` do not work to jump to a next line and tab in the same line, to make the description a bit clearer. I do not know how to get around this problem. I think in the past, I was adding more and more strings to usage using increment `+`, however that was very annoying since the description is some lines long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [argparse docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#formatter-class)

You don't need any special escape characters when making multi line strings with `"""`. You also don't need the `r` in front of the `"""`. All you need to do is supply a `formatter_class` to argparse, like so:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=usage, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
```

This should make it so that it prints exactly how it looks in your code.

Comment: Thanks! I added the solution to my code, and it worked!